# JavaScript insert string into an object iteration

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a function for an Angular Pipe and one of the arguments needs to be a string from the template `*ngFor="let row of tableRows | filter: searchText : keyName"` and then use that to itterate the object in the pipe's function

in component: `let keyName = 'name.value'`

pipe:

```
transform(items: any[], searchText: string, keyName: string = ''): any[] {
    if (!items) {
    return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
    return items;
    }
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    console.log(keyName);
    return items.filter( it => {
    return it.keyName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText); //THIS HERE NEEDS TO MATCH THE STRING PROVIDED
    });
}
```

so lets say the argument string `name.value` is passed into the function, `it.keyName.toLowerCase()` needs to get interpreted as `it.name.value.toLowerCase()`

Comment: `return it[keyName.toLowerCase()].includes(searchText);` ?

Comment: that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [property accessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) (e.g. `object[property]`) to access the nested property.

For instance try the `deepAccessUsingString` function described here:
https://medium.com/@chekofif/using-es6-s-proxy-for-safe-object-property-access-f42fa4380b2c

```
function deepAccessUsingString(obj, key){
  return key.split('.').reduce((nestedObject, key) => {
    if(nestedObject && key in nestedObject) {
      return nestedObject[key];
    }
    return undefined;
  }, obj);
}
```

Use as follows in your code:

```
return deepAccessUsingString(it, keyName).toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
```